# Why do abstract derived classes need to initialize a virtual base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

See the following code:

```
struct Object;

struct Component
{
    Component(Object* obj) { }
};

struct Renderable : public virtual Component
{
    virtual void Render() = 0;
};

struct AnimationRenderer : public Renderable
{
    AnimationRenderer(Object* obj) : Component(obj) { }
    virtual void Render() { }
};
```

This fails to compile, because there is no matching call to `Component::Component()` from `Renderable::Renderable()`.

I can make this sample work by giving `Renderable` a constructor such as `Renderable() : Component(NULL) { }`, **even though Renderable will never be able to initialize Component**.

Because `Renderable` is an abstract class, it can never be instantiated directly. Because it virtually inherits from `Component`, it will never be able to invoke initialization of `Component`.

What is the reason for the language requiring code that will never/can never be invoked?

Comment: I'm also open to suggestions on a better title.

Comment: I think that is what "abstract" means - something we can think of but not as a concrete object.

Comment: abstract class can be instantiated, by the compiler.

Comment: (Title fixed, you said abstract base class but meant virtual base class.  Component is not actually abstract here.)

Comment: @yngccc Could you elaborate on that a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the language doesn't require that.  Your compiler is not using the current C++ rules.

12.6.2p8 says (boldface mine for emphasis):

> [ Note: An abstract class is never a most derived class, thus its constructors never initialize virtual base classes, therefore **the corresponding *mem-initializers* may be  omitted.** — end  note ]

I can't find that rule in C++03, so this is a recognized flaw in C++ that has since been fixed.  Look for a compiler update that supports C++11.

The closest related rule in C++03 I can find was in section 12.6.2p6:

> A *mem-initializer* naming a virtual base class shall be ignored during execution of the constructor of any class that is not the most derived class.

Comment: gcc, clang, and cl all require an initializer. Is this new?

Comment: @dauphic: Sorry about the original false alarm.  I knew that the most derived class would construct virtual bases before non-virtual direct bases, but I was assuming it would look to the directly inheriting class for the constructor arguments.  Can you tell I avoid virtual inheritance?